# upload files to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, go, upload, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload data via an API (go gin) to azure blob storage. Everything works just fine for small files, but when uploading a file bigger than a specific buffer value I get blocks of size 0.

Flow :

- create container
- create block
- read multipart file
- write to block
- upload to block
- commit the block

```
[...]
// Get the uploaded file
file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("File")
[...]


// Initialize buffer
buffer := make([]byte, 4*1048576)

// Read the entire file content into the buffer
n, err := file.Read(buffer)

// Write the data to the blob with the correct offset
_, err = blob.WriteAt(buffer[:n], header.Size)
// commit block
go blob.CommitBlocks()
```

The WriteAt function:

```
func (b *Blob) WriteAt(buf []byte, offset int64) (int, error) {
    log := logger.SugaredLogger().WithContextCorrelationId(b.ctx).With("pkt_id", uuid.New().String(), "action", "WriteAt")
    defer log.Debug("Writing is done...")
    blockIndex := offset / int64(4*1048576)

    // Calculate the index relative to the block list
    indexInList := int(blockIndex)

    // If the block doesn't exist, create it
    if indexInList >= len(b.blockList) || b.blockList[indexInList] == nil {
        sid := uuid.New().String()
        log.Debugf("new block %v id %s", blockIndex, sid)
        b.m.Lock()



        b.blockList[indexInList] = &Block{
            Id:          base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(sid)),
            BlockIndex:  blockIndex,
            Data:        make([]byte, offset), 
            StartOffset: offset,
            blobId:      b.id,
            blobClient:  b.blobClient,
            written:     make(chan int32, 32),
        }

        // Ensure the block list has enough capacity
        if indexInList >= len(b.blockList) {
            b.blockList = append(b.blockList, make([]*Block, indexInList-len(b.blockList)+1)...)
        }

        b.blockCount++
        if c, ok := b.blockListCancel[int64(indexInList)]; ok {
            c()
        }


// upload block
        go b.blockList[blockIndex].UploadBlock(b.ctx, b.blockComplete)

        b.m.Unlock()

    }

    // Calculate the offset relative to the block
    offsetInBlock := offset - b.blockList[indexInList].StartOffset

    log.Debugf("writing %v bytes at offset %v in block %v", len(buf), offsetInBlock, blockIndex)
    b.blockList[blockIndex].M.Lock()

    if b.blockList[indexInList].MaxOffset < offset {
        b.blockList[indexInList].MaxOffset = offset
    }
    b.blockList[blockIndex].M.Unlock()

    //b.blockList[indexInList].WriteData(buf, offsetInBlock)
    b.blockList[blockIndex].WriteData(buf, offset-b.blockList[blockIndex].StartOffset)

    return len(buf), nil
}
```

WriteData function:

```
func (b *Block) WriteData(data []byte, offset int64) {
    dataLen := len(data)
    copy(b.Data[offset:offset+int64(dataLen)], data)
    b.written <- int32(dataLen)
}
```

Block struct:

```
type Block struct {
    Id           string
    BlockIndex   int64
    Data         []byte
    StartOffset  int64
    WrittenBytes int32
    Ready        bool
    Failed       bool
    MaxOffset    int64
    M            sync.Mutex

    w          sync.Mutex
    blobId     string
    blobClient *blockblob.Client
    written    chan int32
}
```

Blob struct:

```
type Blob struct {
    
    id            string
    path          string
    m             sync.Mutex
    mu            sync.RWMutex
    err           error
    ctx           context.Context
    cancelCtx     context.Context
    cancelFunc    context.CancelFunc
    blockComplete chan bool
    committed     bool

    blobClient      *blockblob.Client
    blockList       []*Block
    blockCount      int32
    blockListCtx    map[int64]context.Context
    blockListCancel map[int64]context.CancelFunc
}
```

The UploadBlock function

```
func (b *Block) UploadBlock(ctx context.Context, blockComplete chan bool) {
    concurrency.GlobalWaitGroup.Add(1)
    defer concurrency.GlobalWaitGroup.Done()
    log := logger.SugaredLogger().WithContextCorrelationId(ctx).With("blob_id", b.blobId, "action", "UploadBlock")
    defer log.Debugf("upload block subrutine done...")

    log.Debugf("uploading block id:%v", b.blobId)

    rsc := vfs.NewReadSeekCloser(b.Data)
    response, err := b.blobClient.StageBlock(ctx, b.Id, rsc, &blockblob.StageBlockOptions{})
    _ = rsc.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error staging block %s: %s", b.Id, err)
        b.Failed = true
        blockComplete <- false
        return
    }

    log.Debugf("uploaded %v bytes in block %s: %v", b.WrittenBytes, b.blobId, response)
    b.Ready = true
    blockComplete <- true
    log.Debugf("Write in channel, blockComplete is %v...", blockComplete)
}
```

The CommitBlocks function:

```
func (b *Blob) CommitBlocks() {
    concurrency.GlobalWaitGroup.Add(1)
    defer concurrency.GlobalWaitGroup.Done()
    log := logger.SugaredLogger().WithContextCorrelationId(b.ctx).With("vfs", vfsName, "action", "CommitBlocks", "blob_id", b.id)

    defer log.Debugf("commit subroutine  done...")

    log.Debugf("preparing to commit blocks for blob %v", b.id)

    var (
        i int

        blockList []string
        block     *Block
    )


    for i, block = range b.blockList {
        if block == nil {
            break
        }
        for {
            if block.Failed {
                log.Debugf("failed block encountered, aborting commit")
                return
            }
            if block.Ready {
                log.Debugf("block is ready")
                break
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
        }
        blockList = append(blockList, block.Id)
    }

    log.Debugf("committing %v blocks for blob %v", i, b.id)
    _, err := b.blobClient.CommitBlockList(b.ctx, blockList, &blockblob.CommitBlockListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error while committing blob: %s", err)
        //TODO: Handle error
        return
    }

    b.committed = true
    b.blockComplete <- true

    log.Debugf("committed blob. [id: %v block_count: %v]", b.id, i)
}
```

This works just fine for files < buffer := make([]byte, 4*1048576). If size is > buffer, I get blocks size 0

I have tried to read the file in this way:

```
    var offset int64
    var bufferOffset int
    for {
        n, err := file.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            return
        }

        // Write the data to the blob at the current offset.
        _, err = blob.WriteAt(buffer[:n], offset)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        offset += int64(n)
        bufferOffset += n

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
```

Also, used channels(blockComplete <- true) to lock/unlock (b.m.Lock()/Unlock) to be sure the upload is done after WriteData. Same for CommitBlock, added uploaded := <-b.blockComplete